# Setting Couchbase obsPollInterval & obsPollMax in .NET client

Tags: couchbase

In Couchbase Java client there are obsPollInterval & obsPollMax parameters that can be set on the client.
How do I set the equivalent in .NET client?

[obsPollInterval & obsPollMax](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-java-1.1/#setting-runtime-parameters-for-the-couchbaseconnectionfactorybuilder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly, the two clients have slightly different implementations. The closest thing would be the ObserveTimeout configuration value which defaults to 1 minute and internally the observe will happen every 500ms until either the timeout is reached or operation succeeds.

More information regarding ObserveTimeout can be found here: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-net-1.3/#appendix-configuring-the-net-client-library